# Failed to locate @import file nib.styl

Tags: css, node.js, nib, stylus

Why would I be getting this error? I only have a few things installed, `grunt, grunt-cli, bower, nib, stylus, uglify-js` and `jade`

```
DylanMBPr:Test dylanopet$ stylus -w /Users/dylanopet/Dropbox/Projects/Test watching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/functions/index.styl
Error: /Users/dylanopet/Dropbox/Projects/Test/style.styl:1
1| @import 'nib'
failed to locate @import file nib.styl
at Evaluator.visitImport (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:882:21)
at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
at Evaluator.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:159:18)
at Evaluator.visitRoot (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:713:27)
at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
at Evaluator.visit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:159:18)
at Evaluator.evaluate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:234:15)
at Renderer.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/renderer.js:80:26)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:534:15
at fs.js:266:14
```

This is my error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.21
3 info using node@v0.10.24
4 error Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/dylanopet/Dropbox/Projects/Test/package.json'
5 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
5 error including the npm and node versions, at:
5 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
6 error System Darwin 13.0.0
7 error command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.24/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "test"
8 error cwd /Users/dylanopet/Dropbox/Projects/Test
9 error node -v v0.10.24
10 error npm -v 1.3.21
11 error path /Users/dylanopet/Dropbox/Projects/Test/package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno 34
14 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Update: When I add the following..

```
stylus -u nib style.styl
```

It compiles just fine and everything! Any reason, why I can't simply watch it normally and work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve my problem, I had to add..

```
stylus -u nib -w <dir>
```

I still would love to know why I can't just simple do stylus -w anymore.. But this seems to solve it for now.

Comment: What does that code do? It is incomplete answer unless you provide a brief description.

Comment: I truly wish I knew and others could help explain, you are right being incomplete, but if someone just needs it to work, it does with that now :-)

Still have NO clue why! Not using Stylus anymore. Thanks for the comment buddy.